# Angular and Spring Boot, CORS request did not succeed Error, when HTTPS is active

Tags: angular, spring-boot, ssh, cors

So I have been working on a project for school which is about to be due and I stumbled into a problem.

Whenever I make a POST call to store my data I get the following error: 
[image]

The thing is, it worked fine before I implemented a ssh certificate on the angular side.

I have tried pretty much all solutions that I could find on Stackoverflow or similar sites. I know why it is not working but not how to solve it. So I'd be extremely grateful for someone pointing me into the right direction or showing me what I did wrong.

**My Code:** 
[image]
[image]

**Additional Information:**
The SSH certificate that I implemented on the frontend was signed and generated by my PC, because of that Mozilla is mentioning that the website is **insecure**. Could that affect the CORS Requests/Responses?
This is my first Stackoverflow post.
Not native english.

Comment: Post the code ,not the images please:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 1):

Add the `localhost:8080` too to allowed origins. You don't have it there.

You only have the one with port `4200`.

e.g.

```
.allowedOrigins("https://localhost:8080")
```